# JFrog gem repository source URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, artifactory

We use JFrog as package/gem registry for our internal packages.

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
- RUBY VERSION: 2.6.5 (2019-10-01 patchlevel 114) [x86_64-darwin19]

When I trying to add the generated source link to my gem sources

```sh
gem source -a https://stephan@company.com:PaSsWoRd@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/gems/my-gems/
```

I'm getting an error

```sh
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)
bad URI(is not URI?): "https://stephan@company.com:PaSsWoRd@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/gems/my-gems/"
```

I understand what is written in error, Which is weird to me when it's a jfrog generated URI.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/RubyGems+Repositories

Everything works if I do enable anonymous access, without the auth part

```sh
gem source -a https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/gems/my-gems/
```

I also tried manually adding to ~/.gemrc

```sh
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- https://stephan@company.com:PaSsWoRd@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/gems/my-gems/
- https://rubygems.org/
- http://rubygems.org
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
:concurrent_downloads: 8
```

And it gives the same result

Someone came across it and solved it?

Answer (score 1):

The username has an @.  This looks default, at least when you create and account using an email address.

This will work:

```
gem source -a https://stephan%40company.com:PaSsWoRd@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/gems/my-gems/
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem, + using environment variables

```rb
source "https://#{CGI::escape(ENV["JFROG_USERNAME"])}:#{ENV["JFROG_PASSWORD"]}@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/gems/my-gems/" do
  gem 'my-gem', '0.0.20'
end
```